# How to get Closure Compiler to find window.crypto?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am new to javascript and working on this existing package that uses closure compiler v20120917 to compile a vanilla javascript package into a single minified js file.

I am trying to use crypto:

```
function computeChallenge(buffer) {
    return window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', buffer); 
}
```

but Closure compiler is throwing an error: `ERROR - Property subtle never defined on Window.prototype.crypto`

I can run this on my browser console, and it works fine. Why can't closure compiler find the method? Do I need to import some file, how would I do so?

Comment: what version of the compiler are you using?  are you using an outdated version?  also you should be able to turn off strict mode, so that that is a warning not an error and the compiler can pass

Comment: @user120242 I am using v20120917. Will try updating it. I have tried turning off strict mode but the compiled output file is an empty method.

Comment: ah.  window.crypto is relatively recent.  2012 is definitely too old.  It won't be in their list of globals, so advanced_mode will see it as an undefined property after mangling, and then treat it as a no-op.  If you don't want to upgrade, window['crypto']['subtle']['digest'](...) will also work, if a bit ugly.  Or you can declare it yourself.  But the compiler has had a _lot_ of improvements in the last 8 years, so I'd try to upgrade anyways

Comment: @user120242 Thanks. Running into some issues when upgrading the version. I am also considering using SJCL: http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/
Do you know how can I use that with Closure Compiler?

Comment: There were some big changes since then.  A lot of libraries will not work as-is with closure compiler especially not 2012 version, which has a lot of requirements in the way yo uwrite the code.

Comment: Important reading: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations#restrictions-for-advanced_optimizations

Comment: And you will have to create externs for everything you plan to use: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs

Comment: If you have experience with TypeScript, the process should feel similar.

Comment: J2CL was developed with Closure Complier the easiest way to use it is with Bazel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tool that generates externs automatically by executing the JS and scanning the objects:
JavaScript externs generator
[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jmmk/javascript-externs-generator)
[Runnable Demo](http://jmmk.github.io/javascript-externs-generator/)
Save the extern.js file and then add it to your externs:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
  --js myjs.js --externs extern.js
```

Another way is to just make all calls using string keys when accessing properties
eg: `window["sjcl"]["cipher"]["aes"]()`

Closure Compiler 2012 version will be too old and missing externs for a lot of globals, which Closure Compiler advanced will need or it will treat them as mangleable properties (and subsequently as no-ops).
Upgrading is recommended, because there have been a lot of improvements in the last 8 years, but this may not be practical due to large changes in how the code must be written (as your comment implies).  Below are some options for backporting externs and declaring your own.  If you have experience with TypeScript, the process of creating externs should feel familiar.

Here are some pre-built externs from Google that you should be able to use directly so you can use the crypto API (and other new APIs):

- Repo location for updated global externs: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/externs
- Repo location for WebCrypto API externs: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/browser/w3c_webcrypto.js

For any library that you want to use (without bundling it and compiling it with your program) you will have to declare externs to prevent mangling:
[Declaring Externs Docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs)
This is so that Closure Compiler knows that they are names of functions and objects that already exist and should not be mangled
eg:

```
// myexterns.js
function MyExternFunction(){};
window["MyGlobalVariable"];
```

```sh
java -jar compiler.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
  --js myjs.js --externs myexterns.js
```

Note: Trying to bundle libraries using Closure Compiler Advanced, especially the 2012 version, is most likely not going to be realistically possible unless they already target CC.  Just declare the externs and call it a day.

This doc explains the why you need externs and how the mangling effects your code:
[Restrictions for Advanced Optimizations Docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations#restrictions-for-advanced_optimizations)

Comment: Thanks. The external library I want to use is just one file. http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/sjcl.js. I have already copied this file into my project. But when I try to use sjcl.encrypt, Closure Compiler complains that variable sjcl is undeclared. How can I get it to find sjcl from that file?

Comment: I've added a link to an extern generating tool.  You should probably still clean up the extern after it is generated

Comment: With externs, the file won't be compiled with the minified file right? How should I include the library? Because I am creating an SDK which will be used by other websites.

Comment: Right.  You just include it like you normally include js files.  All it does is maintain the global references so they don't get mangled.  If you want to bundle it like we do with webpack and modules nowadays, you'll have to upgrade closure compiler to a recent version.  Or, and this is probably going to take an unrealistic amount of work to do, modify the library so it is compilable with advanced mode.

Comment: Hey I upgraded my closure compiler version. Added another question about compiling sjcl with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464109/can-i-compile-sjcl-library-with-google-closure-compiler