# Can I compile SJCL library with Google closure compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library, sjcl

I have a vanilla javascript project that is compiled and minified using Closure Compiler v20181210. I want to use SJCL in that project for crypto.

I copied [this file](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/sjcl.js) into my own project and wrote code using the library. But when I try to compile it, Closure Compiler throws a bunch of errors from the library (pasted below).

On the SJCL website, it says that the file is compressed using Google Closure Compressor. So I imagine it should be compatible with Closure? Why is it not compiling then?

Also, I read about externs. But I want all the code to be in a single minified file. With externs, it looks like I would need another import for SJCL.

Some of the Closure Compiler Errors:

```
ERROR - cannot instantiate non-constructor
     [java] sjcl.hash.sha256=function(a){this._key[0]||this._precompute();a?(this._h=a._h.slice(0),this._buffer=a._buffer.slice(0),this._length=a._length):this.reset()};sjcl.hash.sha256.hash=function(a){return(new sjcl.hash.sha256).update(a).finalize()};


ERROR - Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used.
     [java]     (p^l))+d[b];q=l;l=p;p=h;h=n+g|0;n=k;k=f;f=e;e=g+(f&k^n&(f^k))+(f>>>2^f>>>13^f>>>22^f<<30^f<<19^f<<10)|0}c[0]=c[0]+e|0;c[1]=c[1]+f|0;c[2]=c[2]+k|0;c[3]=c[3]+n|0;c[4]=c[4]+h|0;c[5]=c[5]+p|0;c[6]=c[6]+l|0;c[7]=c[7]+q|0}};"undefined"!==typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=sjcl);"function"===typeof define&&define([],function(){return sjcl});


ERROR - actual parameter 3 of AnyStorageProvider.prototype.setItem does not match formal parameter
     [java] found   : string
     [java] required: (number|undefined)
     [java]     toucan.storage.Any.setItem(LOGIN_STATE_CACHE_KEY, loginState, 'session');
```

EDIT: I am running Closure compiler with all these args. When I remove them, the project compiles. But I am not sure if its safe to remove these?

```
<arg line="--jscomp_error accessControls --jscomp_error ambiguousFunctionDecl --jscomp_error checkRegExp --jscomp_error checkTypes --jscomp_error checkVars --jscomp_error const --jscomp_error constantProperty --jscomp_error duplicateMessage --jscomp_error externsValidation --jscomp_error fileoverviewTags --jscomp_error globalThis --jscomp_error internetExplorerChecks --jscomp_error invalidCasts --jscomp_error missingProperties --jscomp_error nonStandardJsDocs --jscomp_error strictModuleDepCheck --jscomp_error typeInvalidation --jscomp_error undefinedNames --jscomp_error undefinedVars --jscomp_error unknownDefines --jscomp_error uselessCode --jscomp_error visibility"/>
```

Comment: from a cursory look, they have a preprocessor that prepares it for compiling with closure [compress_with_closure.sh](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/compress/compress_with_closure.sh) that uses Perl scripts.  So yes, it looks like it will work, but you may need to use _tmpRC.js.  Then, you would need to add the preprocessing into your build chain.  There is a possibility you don't need to do this, and can include them directly, and you can try it first, to see if it works.  You must use the non-minified sources.

Comment: Looks like you have the linter options enabled?  You will want to turn that off.  2018 should be more compatible, and you might be able to just add sjcl's core/ directory to your compile sources for closure compiler.  Not sure if it will do a good job with dead code elimination with the exposed sjcl object.

Comment: @user120242 I figured it out. I am running Closure Compiler with a bunch of args (added to post). When I remove these, project compiles with a lot of warnings. But it works. Is it safe to remove these?

Comment: That would depend on you.  Those are basically the same as having eslint throw errors on your code.  You should not be using the minified file though.  Make sure to include from the core/ directory.

Comment: If you resolve it yourself, post your solution here and accept it as an answer to give this question resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closure Compiler was throwing errors for SJCL because of the `jscomp_error` flags I had on for my own project. Without these, sjcl.js compiles fine.

I fixed it by adding  `--hide_warnings_for='sjcl.js'`

So the rest of the project still uses those flags but sjcl compiles fine.